# Sugar CRM 6.5.14 - Calling REST API with C#

Tags: c#, sugarcrm

Amazingly low on doco when it comes to rest api. Can anyone give me a working example of Sugar CRM REST calls using C#?

I was trying out SugarSharp but it's just listing the services and not coming up with Data(null)

Answer (score 1):

Appreciate this is an old question but for anyone else that comes across it, took me a while to get it all working with creating and updating relationships being the toughest to fathom.

Here is part of a wrapper class I wrote around the v4_1 rest api, hope it helps:-

```
public void Login()
    {
        object loginData = new
        {
            user_auth = new
            {
                user_name = Username,
                password = CalculateMD5Hash(Password)
            }
        };

        string jsonData = CreateFormattedPostRequest("login", loginData);

        var request = GetRestRequest(jsonData, "POST");

        var loginResponse = GetRestResponseByType<LoginResponse>(request);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginResponse.id))
        {
            throw new SugarException(string.Concat("Authorisation Failed for user: {0}, did not retrieve access token", Username));
        }

        SessionID = loginResponse.id;
    }
```

Format the request:-

```
        private string CreateFormattedPostRequest(string method, object data)
    {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

        using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(buffer))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(data, buffer);
        }

        string result = "method=" + method;
        result += "&input_type=JSON&response_type=JSON&rest_data=" + buffer.ToString();

        return result;
    }
```

And finally get the response:-

```
private object GetRestResponseAsObject(HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream input = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(input);
                string buffer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                var responseObj = serializer.DeserializeObject(buffer);

                return responseObj;
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is an example call to the set_entry method:-

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Creates or Updates a single bean, for update ensure that the name_value_list contains the ID of the record
    /// name_value_lists - Dictionary where the keys of the are the SugarBean attributes (columns), the values of the array are the values the attributes should have.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="module">Module to update i.e Account</param>
    /// <param name="record">key value pair object of record, include ID for update</param>
    /// <returns>Returns the updated or created Bean ID</returns>
    public string CreateUpdateBean(string module, object record)
    {
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        parameters.Add("session", SessionID);
        parameters.Add("module_name", module);
        parameters.Add("name_value_list", record);
        parameters.Add("track_view", false);

        string jsonData = CreateFormattedPostRequest("set_entry", parameters);

        var request = GetRestRequest(jsonData, "POST");

        var result = GetRestResponseByType<object>(request);

        return result.ToString();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For calling rest api SugarCRM/SuiteCRM with c#, you can use [SugarRestSharp](https://github.com/mattkol/SugarRestSharp)

Example for create Account:

```
var client = new SugarRestClient(TestAccount.Url, TestAccount.Username, TestAccount.Password);

Account insertAccount = AccountsModule.GetTestAccount();

// -------------------Create Account-------------------
SugarRestResponse response = AccountsModule.CreateAccount(client, insertAccount);

Assert.NotNull(response);
Assert.Equal(response.StatusCode, HttpStatusCode.OK);

string insertId = (response.Data == null) ? string.Empty : response.Data.ToString();

Assert.NotNull(insertId);
Assert.NotEmpty(insertId);
// -------------------End Create Account-------------------
```